# Relative positioning one element in the center and one on the right

Tags: html, css, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a data table and in the header I have:

```
  -The name of the table
  -A button
```

I would like that the name appears in the center and the button on the right.

```
<p:dataTable widgetVar="liveResizeTableWdg"
            var="c"
            value="#{errorContractBean.getDataList(loginBean.usernameLoggedOn)}"
            paginator="true" 
            rows="33"
            paginatorPosition="bottom"
            currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {startRecord}-{endRecord} out of {totalRecords}, 
            Page: {currentPage}/{totalPages}, 
            Total: #{errorContractBean.dataListSize}"
            paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
            rowKey="#{c.uniqueRowID}"
            selection="#{errorContractBean.selectedContract}"
            selectionMode="single" 
            scrollable="true" 
            scrollWidth="auto"
            scrollHeight="auto"
            filteredValue="#{errorContractBean.filteredContracts}"
            resizableColumns="true" 
            liveResize="true" 
            id="liveResizeTable"
            sortMode="single"
            styleClass="table" 
            headerClass="table-header"
            rowStyleClass="rowDef"
            lazy="true">



            <f:facet name="header">
                <span style="font-size: 1.5em; color: red;">Error Transactions</span>
                <p:commandButton value="Refresh" actionListener="#{errorContractBean.refreshPage}" 
                        update=":form" style="position:relative;" oncomplete="liveResizeTableWdg.filter(); liveResizeTableWdg.clearFilters();"> 
                </p:commandButton>  
            </f:facet>
```

Now the name and the button both appear in the center:

Table:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
.........................                       NAME OF THE TABLE - BUTTON                        
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to have this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
......................... NAME OF THE TABLE......................... BUTTON                        
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want the position to be relative, because when I reduce the window the button 
must follow the page.
If I try to specify left or right in css, the 2 elements do not follow the 
size of the page.

Comment: already tried with `style="float: right;"` on the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already tried with `style="float: right;"` on the button?

Comment: sorry on google chrome works ok but on firefox and i.e. it add a white space under the button :((((

Comment: i solved by doing the oveflow visibile

Comment: @Frank, I would suggest to open an answer yourself then rather than accepting one that was not a solution for your issue.

Comment: a downvote? i don't understand. this was initially a comment, then on op request, has become an answer.

Comment: i do not know how put -1 not me. why down vote to me also ? -.-

Comment: @LaszloPapp the answer is partially correct i write in the comment the other part of the correct answer: oveflow visibile ! what is the problem?

Comment: @frank: the fact that SO is not for "partially correct" answers, but for fully!

Comment: @LaszloPapp you put -2 for what i do not know you are crazy man.

Comment: @frank It would still be a good idea to post your own complete answer. You don't have to change the accepted answer if you don't want to, but it would be nice to have something complete, instead of having to look in the comments for additional details.

Comment: @Bart i answerd and i got -2 well ... -.-'

Comment: @frank IMHO your question doesn't deserve a -2. here my contribute, +1.

Answer (score 0):

I did change the button in the following way:

```
<p:commandButton value="Refresh" actionListener="#{errorContractBean.refreshPage}" 
                        update=":form" style="float: right;" oncomplete="liveResizeTableWdg.filter(); liveResizeTableWdg.clearFilters();"> 
</p:commandButton>
```

and the style of the table has

```
overflow: visible
```